# How can i select specific field name using belongTo relationship in laravel model using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-models

I want to fetch only one columns which has name **image_url** from relationship table. relationship on table is belongsTO.
i am confused how to fetch only single column value with belongsTo relation.

below is my model.

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class PropertyImageGallery extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $fillable = ['property_id', 'name', 'size','image_url'];
    
        public function property()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
        }
    }
```

please help me.

Comment: where is you select method?

Answer (score 0):

BelongsTo relationship like below:

```
   public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class,'foreign_key','owner_key');
    }
```

it would be:

```
public function property(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class,'property_id','id');
}
```

Comment: I am asking about i want to fetch only single column, instead of all columns.

Comment: $variable_name->property->image_url

Answer (score 0):

you should call it like this in your controller :

```
$yourParentElement = ParentModel::find(1);
return $yourParentElement ->Property->image_url ;
```

check this for more infos: [Eloquent: Relationships (Belongs To)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class)->select(['property_id', '...']);
}
```